# Start website with playing Flash, at the end continue with a regular website

Tags: html, flash

I want to start my website with a flash movie as an intro. When the flash is finished I want to proceed to my regular website.
I have the flash movie (Full screen) and I have the website. I just can't find the proper connection.
Anyone any idea's

Answer (score 1):

Before realizing this, thing a little bit about SEO.

There a several ways to do realize this "seofriendly".

Here my solution:
Build your HTML page. Add then add your vidoa via "JW-Player" in fullscreen into a container e.G:

```
<div id="myvideo" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index:10">...your video...</div>
```

Very important: The html should exist under your video.

JS-Player has a great JS framework which has a "onfinish_video" event. When your video finishs, you can just hide your container("#myvideo").

Answer (score 0):

You can simply navigate away from your intro page after the intro animation is finished.

To do that, on the last `Frame` of your Flash Intro add the following code:

if you are using AS3:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("*add your page's URL here*"),"_self");
```

if you are using AS2:

```
getURL("*add your page's URL here*", "_blank");
```

You can define a full http:// URL to your page, or if the html/php file is in the same directory just put the file name there :

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("abc.html"),"_self");
```